# How to get unused references using roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have hundreds of projects and I want to remove unused references from each project using roslyn.
I saw this https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/625 but I have no Idea If it's already implemented and If there is a poc example that I can start with.

Please help me If you have any idea how to do this.

Comment: that is not implemented - looks like they are targetting 1.2 or 2.0

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you @Daniel.

Paulo : When a project has a lot of project references, it takes time to load the solution in visual studio and consume more memory for nothing. So I need to remove references to unused projects. We want also to have a clear dependency graph that can  help us when refactoring.

Comment: resharper has tools for this.

Comment: We have resharper 9 but we have hundreds of projects so It's not evident to use "optimize references" command of resharper. We need  also a tool to add in our continuous integration workflow(teamcity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it by registering the compilation action that simply examines all the source trees in a project, finds all symbols referenced by them and considers the assemblies that declare them used, so everything else that's referenced by the project is unused. Here's the analyzer: https://github.com/HellBrick/HellBrick.Diagnostics/blob/ff0b3a415475eda3d2e9927a2ab4638ada5d7148/src/HellBrick.Diagnostics/UnusedReferences/UnusedReferencesAnalyzer.cs

Not sure if this is the most clean and correct way to do this, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: I wanted to launch the analyser, but I'm new to Roslyn so I don't know where to start. Can you please tell me how to execute this analyzer without using plugin.
The only thing I can do now is this :

`var projectFilePath = "ProjectToInspect.csproj";
            var msBuildWorkspace = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var project = msBuildWorkspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectFilePath).Result;`


So whitch  the next step if I want to execute the analyzer ?

Comment: The key methods you're looking for are `Project.GetCompilationAsync()` and `Compilation.WithAnalyzers()`. Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/HellBrick/8d3a6825de12035f3733

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't go further with @HellBrick solution but it seems to me a best solution to try. Instead of that, for each project reference, I remove it then try to compile the project, if the compilation is successful then the reference is unused and if the compilation went wrong I conclude that it is necessary. To accelerate this algorithm, when I check if a reference is useless or not, I replace the other ones by their dll references since I compiled all projects before checking for unused references.